# when i try to run react app showing this error

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile.

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\My-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\My-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error

Answer (score -1):

Apparently a conflict with the casing:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\My-app\...
```

and BaseConfig is looking for:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\achievers\reactProjects\my-app\...
```